# About XML Data Binding to the Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, datagridview

I want to bind the xml file to the datagridview control. but **i don't want to use the dataset** for binding.

. I want to bind the xml file directly to the datagridview. ***IS it possible?*** If yes pls reply me with some example...

thanx...

Comment: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx) you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to accomplish this is by using Linq. First you will need to add a reference to System.XML.Linq, and then use code below:

```
 XDocument oDoc = XDocument.Load("File.xml");
 var myData = from info in oDoc.Descendants("item")
 select new Person
 {
     FirstName = Convert.ToString(info.Element("FirstName").Value),
     LastName = Convert.ToString(info.Element("LastName").Value),
     Age = Convert.ToString(info.Element("Age").Value),
     IsMale = Convert.ToString(info.Element("IsMale").Value)
 };
 oGrid = this.FindName("myDataGrid") as DataGrid;
 oGrid.ItemsSource = myData;
```